# How find this sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}|n-2k|$ closed form or asymptotic behaviour?

Tags: summation, asymptotics

Find the following series   closed form or asymptotic behaviour

$$\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}|n-2k|}{2^n}$$

I use wolfram can't give the  closed form: see [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%7Cn-2k%7C) ,so I think maybe can find the asymptotic expansion?

I think this problem is equivalent find following closed( or asymptotic behaviour)
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\binom{n}{k}(n-2k)+\sum_{k=[n/2]+1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(2k-n)\\
&=n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\binom{n}{k}-\sum_{k=[n/2]+1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\right)-2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{[n/2]}k\binom{n}{k}-\sum_{k=[n/2]+1}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}\right)\\
&=-2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{[n/2]}k\binom{n}{k}-\sum_{k=[n/2]+1}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}\right)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: You can use the $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$ to deal with the terms inside brackets further !

Comment: meaning that $\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\binom{n}{k}=\sum_{k=[n/2]+1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}?$

Comment: now do $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ and use the same thing as before ! :)

Comment: @r9m,But if you this,and then you will take reslut by $=0$?

Comment: I leave it to your fair judgement ! thank you :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A finite sum over $\pm 1$ vectors](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057107/a-finite-sum-over-pm-1-vectors)

Comment: @Aryabhata Its not a duplicate ! They might involve the same identity but the question statements are entirely different.

Comment: @r9m: Think of it as an abstract dupe. So what if this question is missing the context? The idea of closing as dupe is to keep the answers in one place (or at least point to other such answers). In this case, I think it is a valid reason. If the community does not think so, the close vote will decay...

Comment: @Aryabhata I am not sure if I can call the linked question  a more canonical or general scenario of this OP. So I'm not sure if I can call it an 'abstract dupe'. It's true they are just 'minor variants' though. :)

Comment: @r9m: Yes, minor variants for sure (one of the primary reasons the whole abstract dupes things was started).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a very basic asymptotic behavior: Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \cdots$ be i.i.d. symmetric Bernoulli trials with $\Bbb{P}(X_{i} = 1) = \Bbb{P}(X_{i} = -1) = 1/2$. Then for $S_{n} = X_{1} + \cdots + X_{n}$ we have

$$ \frac{1}{2^{n}} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} |n - 2k| = \Bbb{E}|S_{n}|. $$

From the central limit theorem, it follows that $S_{n}/\sqrt{n} \Rightarrow Z$ for a standard normal random variable $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. So we have the following asymptotic relation

$$ \Bbb{E}|S_{n}| \sim \sqrt{n}\, \Bbb{E}|Z| = \sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi}}. $$

Comment: Nice.but can you expalin why $E|(2S_{n})|=\dfrac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}|n-2k|$? detail? especial this form $|n-2k|$ how to have this

Comment: @chinamath: Flip a fair coin $n$ times. Count a head as $+1$ and a tail as $-1$. Then $2S_n$ is the number of heads minus the number of tails. The possible values are $-n,-n+2,\ldots,n-2,n$, i.e., the numbers $n-2k$ for $k=0,\ldots,n$. In fact, $2S_n=n-2k$ when you get $k$ tails, and the probability of $k$ tails is $\frac1{2^n}\binom{n}k$.

Comment: Oh, Now I understand,Thank You +1

Comment: Convergence in distribution does not imply the convergence of the expectations without a supplementary condition. Fortunately, in the present case the fact that $(S_n/\sqrt{n})$ is bounded in $L^2$ is such a supplementary condition.

Comment: @Did, You're right... since the absolute value function is not bounded, we need to appeal to some extra condition satisfied by our choice of $S_{n}$. Thank you for reminding that fact!

Answer (score 9):

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k|n-2k|&=2\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}k(n-2k)\\\\
&=2\left(n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}k-2\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}k\binom{n}k\right)\\\\
&=2n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}k-2\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right)\\\\
&=2n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\left(\binom{n}k-\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right)-\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right)\\\\
&=2n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-1}k-\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right)\\\\
&=2n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-1}k-\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1}\binom{n-1}k\right)\\\\
&=2n\binom{n-1}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\;.
\end{align*}$$

It doesn’t matter whether $n$ is odd or even: if $n$ is even, the $k=\frac{n}2$ term is zero anyway.

Comment: It is nice! Of course, (+1)

Comment: It's Nice too!+1

Comment: @chinamath I think I left enough hint in the comments to complete the answer by yourself ! :-)

Comment: I forget the last $\binom{n-1}{k}$ not $\binom{n}{k}$,so must leave a term

Comment: +1. Pretty nice and cumbersome. I was following another way: By expressing the binomial as a contour integral which right away becomes quite ugly such that I left it altogether.